# Efficiently summarizing a posterior distribution for use in classification

Tags: bayesian, sampling, variational-bayes

I’ve trained a model to do a binary classification task, and I’ve ended up with a posterior over the parameters. I want to make predictions using the posterior over parameters rather than by using a point estimate for the parameters.

My first thought of how to do this was to just sample from the posterior distribution of parameters a bunch of times and then use the mean of all the predictions. I’m pretty sure this approaches the right answer as the number of samples I take approaches infinity.

I’m wondering if there’s a more efficient way of doing this, though. For example, I was considering was approximating the posterior as a weighted sum of Gaussians, and then making each prediction the mean of the Gaussian and taking the weighted mean of the predictions I got that way.

Is there an established solution to this type of problem?

Comment: Roughly how many parameters do you have?  Five is a lot different than 500, for example, when thinking about how to answer this.

Comment: The parameters are a few scalars and a few vectors, where the vectors have about 50 numbers in them.